# who makes the "general rules" and ,"special orders" on behalf of the government in CrPc 432?

Tags: india

Code of criminal procedure 432  and 433 are the main law regarding sentance reduction.

Crpc 432 states the following

> The appropriate Government may, by general rules or special orders give directions as to the suspension of sentences and the conditions on which petitions should be presented and dealt with: Provided that in the case of any sentence (other than a sentence of fine) passed on a male person above the age of eighteen years, no such petition by the person sentenced or by any other person on his behalf shall be entertained, unless the person sentenced is in jail, and-
> (a) where such petition is made by the person sentenced, it is presented through the officer in charge of the jail; or
> (b) where such petition is made by any other person, it contains a declaration that the person sentenced is in jail.

Is it the parliament/legislatures or is it some other body appointed ? various laws that have the power to make rules and by laws under them have the requirement that those rules be laid before the houses of the parliament but it doesn't seem to be the case here

edit;; to the one who voted to close the question because it need clarity. what should I clarify ? I'll try to link more sources and explain it.